# Aws S3 wget vs chunked download speeds

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-s3

My application is trying to read a file in chunks of 2 MB from S3 using S3 java SDK. Its a multi threaded app that downloads distinct chunks. I am running this app on a m5.xlarge instance (4 cores, 16 Gig RAM).

The maximum download bandwidth I am getting using chunked download is ~30 MBps whereas if I use wget on the same file after making it public, I get speeds up to 100 MBps. I looked at iftop and tcptrack's network monitoring and it looks like even with the chunked parallel download the same connections are being reused.(same ports are being used) What can be the possible reasons for this and how can I improve my read performance?

This is what I get from my application

> Downloaded 500 chunks in 34seconds bandwidthInMBps: 29.41176470588235
>   ChunkSizeInMB: 2, threadCount: 16

This is from wget

```
 rksupport@bolt:~$ wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/aXXXXXXXXXX/upload.tar.gz
--2018-09-19 22:36:40--  https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXX/upload.tar.gz
Resolving s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.236.29
Connecting to s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com)|54.231.236.29|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3122206720 (2.9G) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: 'upload.tar.gz'

upload.tar.gz                                                          100%[==========================================================================================================================================================================>]   2.91G  91.6MB/s    in 31s     

2018-09-19 22:37:11 (95.1 MB/s) - 'upload.tar.gz' saved [3122206720/3122206720]
```

Comment: Your chunk size is too small. At 100 MBps, a 2 MB chunk takes 20 ms. The connection setup overhead is slowing you down. Basically you want to break the download into 2 to 4 streams, not 500 tiny streams.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried with even bigger chunks and fewer threads. Results are in the same ballpark 

Downloaded 16 chunks in 54 seconds
ChunkSizeInMB: 100, threadCount: 8, randomAccess: false, bandwidthInMBps: 29.62962962962963"

Downloaded 8 chunks in 36 seconds
ChunkSizeInMB: 100, threadCount: 4, randomAccess: false, bandwidthInMBps: 22.22222222222222

Comment: Using your code, what are the numbers for 1 stream (disable chunking) to compare with wget?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring S3 Transfer acceleration?

Do you have the S3 Endpoint in your VPC?

Both of those should make your downloads faster.

Comment: S3 transfer acceleration does not help as my Ec2 instance is in the same region as the bucket. And yes vpc endpoint is set.